# Variable Routes in SvelteKit that Always Hit the Same File

Tags: sveltekit

I've been reading the [advanced routing](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing) section of the SvelteKit docs, and I can't quite figure out how to do something.

I want **all routes** to hit the same `+page.server.ts` file:

```js
import type { PageServerLoad } from '../$types';

export const load = (async ({ params }) => {
  console.log('Logging in +page.server.ts');

  console.log(params);
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```

`/a/b/c` should log:

```js
{
  first: 'a',
  second: 'b',
  third: 'c'
}
```

`/a/b` should log:

```js
{
  first: 'a',
  second: 'b',
  third: ''
}
```

`/a` should log:

```js
{
  first: 'a',
  second: '',
  third: ''
}
```

I think my folder structure should look like this:

```
/routes
- /first
- /first/second
- /first/second/third
```

But I need them all to be `(optional)` and always hit the `+page.server.ts` inside `/routes`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to apply to all routes, make it a layout, so in this case `+layout.server.ts`.

Optional parameters use `[[parameter]]`, so you get `routes/[[first]]/[[second]]/[[third]]`.

But they do not appear in `params` if not set, so if you want a default like an empty string you have to set that yourself in code.

```js
const resolved = {
    first: '',
    second: '',
    third: '',
    ...params,
};
console.log(resolved)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where does `+layout.server.ts` go? I've tried putting it in `/routes` and `/routes/[[first]]/[[second]]/[[third]]` and I get `Error: Not found: /a/b/c` in both cases.

Comment: Do you have a `+page.svelte` in the directory of the route? Also, technically everything here is just one route, so you do not necessarily need to use a layout. If the layout should apply to all possible routes it should go directly in `routes`. Here you can just use `+page.server.ts` and `+page.svelte` in the deepest directory.

Comment: Ah, I was missting the `+page.svelte` file in the deepest directory. I incorrectly assumed it would go in the root of `/routes`. Thanks again for your help!